Implementing traits for dyn traits
I'm having issues in getting Rust to compile with this particular situation I simplified to this example.
struct LeafNode {
    data: f64,
}

struct ContainerNode {
    data: f64,
    previous: Rc<RefCell<dyn Node>>,
}

trait Node {
    fn data(&self) -> f64;
}

impl Node for LeafNode {
    fn data(&self) -> f64 {
        self.data
    }
}

impl Node for ContainerNode {
    fn data(&self) -> f64 {
        self.data
    }
}

impl Add for &dyn Node {
    type Output = ContainerNode;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> ContainerNode {
        let self_ref = Rc::new(RefCell::new(self));
        ContainerNode {
            data: self.data() + other.data(),
            previous: self_ref,
        }
    }
}

(In my particular scenario, implementing Add, Mul, Sub, etc, make sense because this is an expression engine.)
At this point the compiler throws the following error:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&dyn Node: Node` is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:187:23
    |
187 |             previous: self_ref,
    |                       ^^^^^^^^ the trait `Node` is not implemented for `&dyn Node`
    |

And that's true -- the trait is implemented for references of the implementors of the trait, not for implementors of the trait.
However, doing impl Add for dyn Node generates errors about dyn Node size not being known at compile time, nor it should be -- so this is where I'm lost.
My goal is to write this trait as a generic that will unwind into the methods that do the combinations of all of my Node types. I'd prefer static dispatch approach. I know this is valid because if I write them myself, the compiler will just accept them -- so I know the problem is related from my implementation of the trait.
How can I fix impl Add so that it adapts to this structure?

impl Node for &dyn Node or impl<N: Node + ?Sized> Node for &N.

@ChayimFriedman That gets me a bit closer but now I'm in issues with lifetimes, and I don't understand why, because my variables are just used to be consumed in the functions, except for Rc<...>. Would you mind elaborating a bit further?

any references like &dyn Node have a lifetime associated with them, however since you don't annotate Rc<RefCell<dyn Node>> with a lifetime it is inferred to be 'static. So you cant store any non-'static references within previous. So you can't put &dyn Node in there (unless you constrain it to be &'static dyn Node, but that likely isn't useful to you).

impl<N: Node> Add for N?

@Jmb I took your suggestion but then I got complaints about local vs. foreign traits (if I use generics for everything), and if I don't I get complaints about the size not being known. I think at this point the problem is closely related to my lack of deep understanding of traits, so I'll have to dig deeper in this. Thanks though!
